# Passing parameters with htaccess

Tags: php, url, mod-rewrite

For example, I have the following URL: *www.site.com?page=products&action=view&id=1023*
I have this PHP code:

```
<?php
echo $_GET['page'];
echo $_GET['action'];
echo $_GET['id'];
?>
```

That wors fine.
But I want to rewrite the URL to

> www.site.com/products/view/1023

So, the names of the arguments, and some characters like ? and & are removed.
The URL would be:

> www.site.com/products/view/1023

How do I say to PHP which GET variable I want to use?
The names in the UL are away.
I am making a PHP router, and I don't understand how parameters are passed by rewritten URL's.

Comment: What does your .htaccess look like?

Comment: I advise you to read this: http://www.sitepoint.com/guide-url-rewriting/

Comment: The rewrite rule itself will specify the GET parameters you use.  E.g. you create a rule to "rewrite" `www.site.com/products/view/1023` into `www.site.com?page=products&action=view&id=1023`, thus meaning that your PHP script doesn't need to change.  I suggest you read a good tutorial on how to write such rules.